# Как создать новый jwt токен с обновленными Claims

Tags: c#, jwt, blazor, .net-6

Чтобы обновить Claims-ы пользователя Создаю новый токен в контроллере:

```
User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(modelId);
var claims = await GetClaims(user);
var tokenOptions = GenerateTokenOptions(signingCredentials, claims);
var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);
Log.Information($"[token = {token}]");
return Ok(token);
```

Обновляю полученный токен в LocalStorage и оповещаю, что он обновлен:

```
public async Task SetToken(string? token, string username)
        {
            await Logout();
            await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("authToken", token);
            ((AuthStateProvider)_authStateProvider).NotifyUserAuthentication(username);
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
        }
```

Обнавляю HttpClient и сервисы Refit на странице Blazor:

```
var token = await LocalStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");
            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            MainPageService = RestService.For<IMainPageService>(HttpClient);
            ResourcesService = RestService.For<IResourcesService>(HttpClient);
```

Пользователь остается авторизованным. Но запросы Refit возвращают 401. Может есть способы обновить Claims только в компонентах .razor? Или я что-то делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

Во время логина, я получал новый токен с помощью HttpClient.

А новый токен я получил с помощью Refit и в результате токен был получен с символом "\u0022" в начале и в конце.

Comment: Нужно десерилизовать полученный json в строку